# rsync command with multiple jump servers

Tags: rsync

I have a server than I can only access via 2 jump servers:

```
user@mylaptop$ ssh jumpserver1 ssh user2@jumpserver2.other.network ssh targetserver "bash -c 'hostname;whoami'"
targetserver
user2
```

`jumpsever2` and `targetserver` are in the same network, `mylaptop` and `jumpserver1` are in another network.
My user on `mylaptop` and `jumperver1` is the same. My user on `jumpserver2` and `targetserver` is another: `user2`.
Key pairs are deployed between:

- `mylaptop` and `jumpserver1`
- `jumpserver1` and `user2@jumpserver2`
- `jumpserver2` and `targetserver`

I want to write the corresponding rsync command in order to send files from `mylaptop` to `targetserver`:

```
mylaptop$ rsync -az /path1 user2@targetserver:/path2
```

I've found command line for **one** jump server but not for **two**.

So far,

```
mylaptop$ rsync -az /path1 -e 'ssh jumpsever1 ssh user2@jumpserver2.other.network ssh targetsever' targetsever.other.network:/path2
```

do not work (*bash: targetserver: command not found*)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've adapted the command from [Rsync files via intermediate host](https://superuser.com/questions/1115715/rsync-files-via-intermediate-host) and it worked:

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -o "ProxyCommand ssh -A jumpserver1 ssh user2@jumpserver2.other.network -W %h:%p"' /path1 user2@targetserver.other.network:/path2
```

Excepted that I am asked for a password despite the key pair deployment.