# How to remotely download from a server that's 'firewalled' by another server?

Tags: ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux, scp, wsl2

I need to access and download a catalog of stars from a remote server for my thesis work from outside my university. The server that holds the data (let's call it **target**) can only be accessed from outside the university's internet through another server (say, **bouncer**) that acts as a firewall. I must go through **bouncer** to get to **target** and the data.

I have no space allocated to my account in **bouncer**, so I cannot transfer files from **target** to it and then to my computer. The only way would be to, somehow, I think, make it so the transfer (I'm using the `scp` command on wsl2) goes from **target**, through **bouncer**, and directly to my computer, without messing with the not existing space.

So, is it possible to remotely download from a server only accessible through a second server? It is possible for me to ask for access to a VPN (which I have no idea how it would go), but the process takes at least a week, and that's a week I could be working.

Edit: I'm currently running Windows 11 Home and the Windows Subsystem for Linux.

Comment: I wonder if you could ssh tunnel a SCP transfer...

Comment: I could learn to use another protocol if it would let me do what I'm looking for

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/964244/rsyncing-directories-through-ssh-tunnel rsync maybe

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/456438/how-do-i-scp-a-file-through-an-intermediate-server possibly your question MIGHT be a dupe of this